minimum_required_approvers default and choosable value
I have a short question. In our Terraform code, we have a azuredevops_check_approval resource. The optionnals settings minimum_required_approvers and requester_can_approve are not set so the default value are used.
In our .tfstate, in the informations related to the azuredevops_check_approval resource, we have the informations about the two optionnals feature :
"minimum_required_approvers": 0,
"requester_can_approve": false,

but here is my question:
the default value for "minimum_required_approvers" is not 1 ? Here it seems to be 0 but an approval is still needed when we run a pull request with terraform in our devops repository ?
Here is our written code for the azuredevops_check_approval resource :
resource "azuredevops_check_approval" "apim_team_environment_approval" {
  for_each             = local.envs
  project_id           = data.azuredevops_project.project_apim_dna.id
  target_resource_id   = azuredevops_environment.apim_team_env[each.key].id
  instructions         = "Please verify terraform plan in the azure pipeline before approval"
  target_resource_type = "environment"
  approvers = [
    azuredevops_team.apim_team.id
  ]
}

the official documentation of terraform isn't complete enough to answer to my question.
Thank you in advance for your time and I hope that my question is clear enough

As mentioned in the azuredevops_check_approval documentation, the minimum_required_approvers property is applicable when there is more than 1 approver.
This corresponds to the Minimum number of approvals required dropdown in the portal, which is visible when adding 2 or more approvers:


the default value for "minimum_required_approvers" is not 1?

Given that setting required approvers in an environment is not mandatory, I guess it makes sense to set the default value to 0.

an approval is still needed when we run a pull request with terraform in our devops repository?

You can configure approvers in both branch policies and Azure DevOps environments:

azuredevops_check_approval can be used to include the minimum number of approvers in an Azure DevOps environment - for example, to approve a stage or job in a pipeline.

azuredevops_branch_policy_min_reviewers can be used to set the minimum number of reviewers in a branch policy - for example, when pull requests are created.


